# ES6 / JS: Regex for replacing delve with conditional chaining

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

How to replace delve with conditional chaining in a vs code project?

e.g.

```
delve(seo,'meta')
delve(item, "image.data.attributes.alternativeText")
```

desired result

```
seo?.meta
item?.image.data.attributes.alternativeText
```

Is it possible using find/replace in Visual Studio Code?
[image]

Comment: What is `delve`, what does it do?

Comment: Can you show us your attempt at writing a regex, please?

Comment: @Bergi its a libary for savely retrieving properties in an object, see https://github.com/hughfdjackson/delve I wanna get rid of it since conditional chaining does the same thing without a third party libary. Thats why i am asking for a regex to replace all occurences in a bigger project. I am trying around in regexr but i don't really know regex

Comment: A RegEx alone is incapable of parsing JS so technically you can't. Practically a RegEx will suffice though, assuming you have no odd cases there like `delve(obj["a,b"], "key")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose the following RegEx:

`delve\(\s*([^,]+?)\s*,\s*['"]([^.]+?)['"]\s*\)`

and the following replacement format string:

`$1?.$2`

Explanation: Match `delve(`, a first argument up until the first comma (lazy match), and then a second string argument (no care is taken to ensure that the brackets match as this is rather quick'n'dirty anyways), then the closing bracket of the call `)`. Spacing at reasonable places is accounted for.

which will work for simple cases like `delve(someVar, "key"`) but might fail for pathological cases; always review the replacements manually.

Note that this is explicitly made incapable of dealing with `delve(var, "a.b.c"`) because as far as I know, VSC format strings don't support "joining" variable numbers of captures by a given string. As a workaround, you could explicitly create versions with two, three, four, five... dots and write the corresponding replacements. The version for two dots for example looks as follows:

`delve\(([^,]+?)\s*,\s*['"]([^.]+?)\.([^.]+?)['"]\s*\)`

and the format string is `$1?.$2?.$3`.

You write:

> e.g.
> `delve(seo,'meta')`
> `delve(item, "image.data.attributes.alternativeText")`
> desired result
> `seo?.meta`
> `item?.image.data.attributes.alternativeText`

but I highly doubt that this is intended, because `delve(item, "image.data.attributes.alternativeText")` is in fact equivalent to `item?.image?.data?.attributes?.alternativeText` rather than the desired result you describe. To make it handle it that way, simply replace `[^.]` with `.` to make it accept strings containing any characters (including dots).

Comment: @user3169083 simply replace `[^.]` with `.` (all characters but the dot vs. "all" characters). Edited the answer.

Comment: Just read your updated answer. Okay i see in that case i will use the workaround you described. Can you show the version for two dots, sorry need one more to fully understand

Comment: @user3169083 edited. Also fixed a typo where it was `.?` instead of `?.`.

Comment: thank you saved me a couple of hours i was close to do it by hand :-). Time to learn that RegEx ! Marked as answered